# LaTeX input from subfolders and subsubfolders

Tags: input

although I've read a lot of postings regarding LaTeX import from subfolders, I could not find a solution to my issue and hope you can help me out.

I'm working on a large LaTeX file which consists of several reports that have been created beforehand. Now I want to join them and this keeps making trouble with the `\input` command.

Here's the folder structure I am required to use: There is the main folder containing "large_report.tex" and a subfolder named "reports". In this subfolder there are several folders of reports like "report1", "report2" etc. Within every report's folder there is a file "reportX.tex" (where X is the number of the current report) and again two folders named "sections" and "figures".
I tried to figure this structure here (sorry to name the file before the folders but it's more clear then):

```
/
|
|- large_report.tex
|
|- reports
  |- report1
  | |- sections
  |   | - section1.tex
  |   | - section2.tex
  |   | - section3.tex
  | |- figures
  |   | - figure1.pdf
  |   | - figure2.pdf
  |   | - figure3.pdf
  | |- report1.tex

  |- report2
  | |- sections
  |   | - sectionA.tex
  |   | - sectionB.tex
  |   | - sectionC.tex
  | |- figures
  |   | - figureA.pdf
  |   | - figureB.pdf
  |   | - figureC.pdf
  | |- report2.tex

  |- more reports...

|- more folders...
```

The clue is: every `reportX.tex` uses `\input{sectionY}` to include the files in the `sections` folder and in these section files (`sectionZ.tex`) there are `\includegraphic` commands like `\includegraphic{figures/figureA}`.

Finally, large_report.tex should use `\include{reports/report1.tex}` but this throws errors for every reference of reports1.tex and its section files.

I found a solution to create "MyPath"-makros but as far as I see, this would be necessary for all report paths, right? Plus, I would need to rename all paths in all section files.

Maybe I am mising something here and you will say, that this structure is ridiculous anyway.
But, is there a solution which is simplier than renaming all paths?

Btw, I use TeXstudio (pdflatex) for Windows.

Comment: What about the package [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) or the tool [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/). Or see the general [CTAN topic on 'subdocs'](https://www.ctan.org/topic/subdocs).

Comment: Thanks for moving my question to the right place!
And thank you for your answer, jon!
I browsed the packages and found 'subdocs' well suitable for my report problem. :) Thanks for your help and this advice!